# Cómo reemplazar los valores '?' en una dataframe en R

Tags: r, dataframe

Estoy tratando de reemplazar los valores '?' en un Dataframe por NA, para poder luego usar la librería MissForest en ese DataFrame.

El Dataframe son columnas con valores numéricos y factores.

Lo que he intentado es usar la función na_if() de la librería dplyr, que se supone que te reemplaza cualquier carácter por NA, pero no parece que funcione.
De momento no hay manera de que cambie los '?', he probado a ponerlo como "\?", he probado el mutate (pero me da error).

Este es el código que estoy usando.

```
for (columna in 1:ncol(df)){
  columna <- na_if(columna, '?')
}

df <- missForest(df)$ximp
str(df)
head(df)

´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con dplyr, una posible solucion es:

```
df %>% mutate(across(.cols = everything(),.fns = ~ ifelse(. == "?", NA_character_, .)))
```

Con el across puedes aplicar una función a cada columna, en este caso todas, y la función en este caso seria ifelse, donde preguntamos por "?" y si lo encuentra lo reemplazamos por un NA

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona, lo guardo como apunte para el futuro aunque encontré una solución más simple (ganas de complicarme muchas veces); al cargar los datos tienes la opción de cambiar a NA las caracteres que consideres ```read.csv(data, na.strings = '?')```

Comment: Es bueno encontrar soluciones alternativas, en tu caso no sabia que el origen de tu problema era al momento de cargar los datos, pero aun así muchas gracias por el dato :)